# radio button name change for validation validation

Tags: javascript

i want to change radio button name like sex1, sex2 for validation.But how can I add the value of i

```
for(i=1;i<=no_applicant;i++) {
  var sex = document.edu.sex+i+;
  for (var j=0; j<sex.length; j++) {
    if (sex [j].checked)
      break;
  }
  if (j==sex.length) {
    alert("Sex field for "+i+" applicant  cannot leave blank");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.g. `document.edu["sex" + i]`.

In Javascript,`foo.bar` is just a convenient shorthand for `foo["bar"]` that works when the key is a literal string that matches the form of an identifier name.  For anything more complicated, use the bracket form.